# How I can get the distinct result?

Tags: elasticsearch

What I am trying to do is the query to elastic search (ver 6.4), to get the unique search result (named eids). I made a query as below. What I'd like to do is first text search from both 2 fields called eLabel and pLabel, and get the distinct result called eid. But actually the result is not aggregated, showing redundant ids from 0 to over 20. How I can adjust the query?

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Brazil Capital",
      "fields": [
        "eLabel",
        "pLabel"
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 200,
  "_source": [
    "eid",
    "eLabel"
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "eids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "eid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my current mappings are as follows.

- eid : id of entity
- eLabel: entity label (ex, Brazil)
- prop_id: property id of the entity (eid)
- pLabel: the label of the property (ex, is the capital of, is located at ...)

```
  "mappings": {
    "entity": {
      "properties": {
        "eLabel": {
          "type": "text" ,
          "index_options": "docs" ,
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        } ,
        "eid": {
          "type": "keyword"
        } ,
        "subclass": {
          "type": "boolean"
        } ,
        "pLabel": {
          "type": "text" ,
          "index_options": "docs" ,
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        } ,
        "prop_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        } ,
        "pType": {
          "type": "keyword"
        } ,
        "way": {
          "type": "keyword"
        } ,
        "chain": {
          "type": "integer"
        } ,
        "siteKey": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "docId": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by redundant ids from 0 to 20. Are you saying you'd only want to display certain term fields i.e. `eids` based on a particular format of text (or numerics or combination of both)? For e.g. are you saying this what you observe and you'd want them to not appear in your result `{
          "key" : 0,
          "doc_count" : 2
        }`

Comment: Please share your index mapping as well.

Comment: I added my mapping schema

Comment: @Kamal What I expect is the RDB style result. For example, I expect to get the result like ```SELECT DISTINCT eid FROM entity WHERE eLabel = "Brazil" AND pLabel = "capital" ```. The current result is that top 20 search result have the same eid because result pLabels are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can make use of the below query using [Bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). Don't think anything is wrong with aggregation query, just replace the query you have with the bool query I've mentioned and I think it would suffice.

When you make use of [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query, it would retrieve even if the document has `eLabel = "Rio is capital of brazil"` & `pLabel = "something else entirely here"`

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "eLabel": "capital"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "pLabel": "brazil"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 200,
  "_source": [
    "eid",
    "eLabel"
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "eids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "eid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if you only want the values of `eid` and do not want the documents, you can set `"size":0` in the above query. That way you'd only have aggregation results returned.

Let me know if this helps!!

Comment: Oh, of course it helps a lot. It works. Thank you very much